# How to interpret skimage orientation to straighten images?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I have a bunch of images that I am trying to straighten so the images are horizontal (major axis is horizontal) but I don't understand the `orientation` output from [regionprops method](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops) in skimage. How to convert it into degrees ? What is the axis reference for the output angle ?

Here is the skimage doc:

> orientation : float. Angle between the 0th axis (rows) and the major axis
> of the ellipse that has the same second moments as the region, ranging
> from -pi/2 to pi/2 counter-clockwise.

**My question**:
Given the orientation, how do I calculate the angle in degrees to rotate the image so that the major axis is horizontal with skimage?

### Code sample

Basically, the main major and minor axis of this object belong to index 1 of the pandas dataframe. The orientation of the object is -1.184075 and should belong to the major axis.

```
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops_table

# connected pixels of same label get assigned a value
label_img = label(binary_image_here)
props = regionprops_table(label_img, properties=('centroid',
                                             'bbox',
                                             'orientation',
                                             'major_axis_length',
                                             'minor_axis_length'))

df = pd.DataFrame(props)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the doc you provide, **orientation is in radians**, ranging from -pi/2 to pi/2 counter-clockwise:

> orientation : float. Angle between the 0th axis (rows) and the major
> axis of the ellipse that has the same second moments as the region,
> ranging from -pi/2 to pi/2 counter-clockwise.

Moreover, as it is said in the [regionpropos doc](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops), since 0.16.0, they use "rc" corrdinates everywhere. They say for the majority of computation you could find the old results with a simple transformation, but for others, it is more complicated, such as the orientation:

> For example, the new orientation is π/2 plus the old orientation.

Which means that the right formula to get the angle you want is this one:

```
angle_in_degrees = orientation * (180/np.pi) + 90
```

And the orientation refers to this angle on the image:
[image]

**Now:** If you want your major axis and the 0th axis align, then rotate your image by `-angle_in_degrees`:

```
from skimage.transform import rotate
rotate(image, -angle_in_degrees, resize=True)
```

Comment: Ah ok, I see. So, I convert radians to degrees and then rotate so the total equals either -90 or 90 depending on whether the radian was positive of negative. If the radian is negative, convert the radian to degrees and add the remaining degree value so the total is -90 degrees and vice-versa.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Is it clearer now how you should proceed ?

Comment: Ah yes much clearer, thanks! One thing though. The major axis in the example picture I have looks like your first image; however, the orientation by skimage is negative (negative also in degrees) and not positive. Why is that? Should I also be considering the position of minor axis in that case?

Comment: You are right, I did not understand it first but it comes from an update they have done. To compute the right angle you should add pi/2 to the orientation (or 90 to the angle in degrees). I have added that to the answer.